# jQuery to filter elements with class names based on selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble with the following:

When a user selects a region, and then selects a country (currently functionality is set to only work for **Australia**) The list elements will hide and display only the lists that contain the class Australia.

What I'm having trouble with however is, the class name has to match the value from the array in my JS. So for example, united states would appear as two classes but the string won't match.

The user can only select one country at a time, but an image can be assigned multiple countries, and based on the country that is selected, only the elements with the matching class name should appear.

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/Canvasandcode/pen/zMxVgm

Snippet:

```
`$('#selectCountry').on('change', function() {
        var countrySelected = $(this).val();
        var brandToDisplay = "." + countrySelected;
        var brandLogo = $('.brand-logo--wrapper .icon--wrapper');

        console.log(countrySelected);

        if (brandLogo.hasClass(countrySelected)) {
            $(brandLogo).fadeOut();
            $(brandToDisplay).fadeIn();
        } else if ($('#selectCountry').is(':empty')) {
            $(brandLogo).fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(brandLogo).fadeIn();
        }
    });`
```

Comment: If you are creating an element with `class="united states"` then if you do not want to change that to be a single class, you would have to select it with `.united.states`, no spaces

Comment: but how can I achieve this with out having to specifically selecting a class (eg. .United.States, .United.Kingdom?) @taplar

Comment: I thought you wanted to match on class?  That's what your if statement is doing?

Comment: Instead of saving in an array the countries to check if it contains or not, I would recommend you to save in a key/value object the country and the css.

Comment: @BrankVictoria I agree that would be a more efficient way for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hyphenize those values, like `var hyphenizedCountryName = countrySelected.split(' ').join('-')` instead of `countrySelected` in the snippet you've shared.

```
$('#selectCountry').on('change', function() {
    var countrySelected = $(this).val();
    var hyphenizedCountryName = countrySelected.split(' ').join('-')
    var brandToDisplay = "." + hyphenizedCountryName;
    var brandLogo = $('.brand-logo--wrapper .icon--wrapper');

    console.log(hyphenizedCountryName);

    if (brandLogo.hasClass(hyphenizedCountryName)) {
        $(brandLogo).fadeOut();
        $(brandToDisplay).fadeIn();
    } else if ($('#selectCountry').is(':empty')) {
        $(brandLogo).fadeIn();
    } else {
        $(brandLogo).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

So the `console.log` for "united states" is "united-states" and for one word country names it's unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution! That worked perfectly :)